# Screenshot thumbnails can't be dragged to most applications

Tags: mojave, screen-capture

I am running Mojave (10.14.2). Since the introduction of the floating screenshot thumbnail, I have been unable to drag these thumbnails to most applications, with few exceptions such as Telegram and Notes.

I'm not sure how something as prominent as this draggable thumbnail is incompatible with the rest of macOS's drag and drop systems, so I feel like I'm missing something.

An example of an app that won't support this (but supports normal file drag&drop from Finder) is Slack. In fact, I really struggle with this one as one of my main use-cases is taking screenshots and sending them via Slack. I currently right-click on the thumbnail, copy it to the clipboard, then paste into Slack.

Is there a way to get full drag&drop functionality on macOS's screenshot thumbnails?

Comment: Slack is not made in "native" languages such as Swift/ObjC. They do not get the newest features for free like many other well written apps. I've made the same request to Slack team month ago and that's their answer: " I'd also love to have this ability. The good news is that this is something that we are working on." So there's not much you can do about it before they update the app.

Comment: Agreed. The new screenshot functionality is very frustrating since the file does not even appear on the desktop until the preview hides itself, so it just introduces a delay before you can drag it anywhere. Very annoying. I have not found a solution.

Comment: @Doug: You can turn off those previews in the Cmd+Shift+5 screenshot "Options" menu; uncheck "Show Floating Thumbnail". You can also swipe the screenshot to the right with a drag or with a Magic Mouse/Trackpad gesture.

Comment: I am too annoyed this doesn't work with Slack on Chrome (don't care about their Electron app)

Comment: Apple seems to have intentionally not allowed this. I suspect they're trying to get people to move to an iOS/iPad-centric way of "sharing" the screenshot rather than interacting with it like a file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the screenshot (My favourite shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>)
2. Double click the miniature
3. In the "editor" click share button and select Mail[image: where to find Mail share]
4. You'll see a mail compose window. Drag the picture to the application you originally wanted to drop to (e.g. Slack)[image].

Comment: This doesn't look any easier than dragging it from a folder screenshot is saved to, or using regular send file button in slack.

Comment: You might as well just disable the screenshot helper and drag from your desktop at this point.

Comment: @duane: How do you disable the helper?

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I've found is adding the Desktop (or wherever you keep your screenshots) folder to the dock and disabling the thumbnail, this way I can easily drag and drop a recent screenshot.